# Can anyone explain how to get a hybris project set up in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, sap-commerce-cloud

I am following the trails on the wiki and I am able to get the Hybris project set up in Eclipse just fine.  But because I am new to Intellij Idea and I am still trying to grasp the idea of "projects" instead of "workspaces", I am having a hard time translating the Eclipse setup steps into intellij idea steps.  I have Hybris - how do I "open" it in Intellij Idea?  (Apologies ahead of time for the noob question but appreciate any input someone can give me).

Answer (score 23):

1.Open "**Intellij**"

2.Click on "**Configure**" drop down at below on right side

3.Select "**Plugins**" from drop down

4.Install "**SAP Commerce Developers ToolSet**" plugin.

5.Restart **Intellij** again. Click on "**+New Project**"

6.Select "**Empty Project**" and then click "**Next**"

7.Give "**Project name**" like. "**vip**" or anything which you want to give and then click on Finish.

8.Close the popup, which will come automatically.

9.Click File->New ->"**Project from Existing Resource**".

10.Select "**bin**" folder from your project setup.

11.In popup, Select radio button "**import project from external model**". And Select "**hybris**"

12.Click on  "**Next**" two more times. Then it will show all the extensions which you have imported for your project

13. Click on "**Next**" two more times. Now it open the "**intellij**" workspace.
14. pop up will come  and select "**This window**"

Your hybris is ready to use in **Intellij**

Comment: This procedure is only for IntelliJ 2020 and above version. For below versions, You can directly select Import project and follow from Step 9.

Answer (score 18):

Just install ["Hybris Integration"](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525-hybris-integration) plugin it will do everything automatically. You will be able to import Hybris projects just like maven or gradle based projects. That plugin provides Hybris integration into Intellij IDEA and another IDE based on it.

You can install it to your IDE directly from the [repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525) by clicking on the "Browse Repositories" button in Settings/Plugins dialog.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, and link only answers are discouraged, since if the link changes the info is lost.

Comment: Still, this is interesting. You could also look to add change detection and rebuild on *-items.xml and *-beans.xml.

Comment: Is there an equivalent plugin for NetBeans?

Comment: @StuartSiegler You won't be able to achieve the same results manually. That plugin is already being developed more than 4 years and it exploits a lot of Ingellij API to make it work. The way Intellij set ups its projects by default is not really matching the way Hybris works, to make it worse Hybris has different classpathes in runtime and during build time and the plugin tries to match that as closely as possible by customizing Intellij API.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have not seen such plugin for Netbeans.

Comment: @user3122271 It has been in progress for a while. We have a task for that.

Comment: This is not free anymore.

Answer (score 9):

First, your extension dependencies should be clear. Normally, the basic dependencies in every project are:
`your storefront extension` depends on `your facade extension` depends on `your core extension` depends on `platform` and `voucher` and `mediaconversion` (and probably many more) . Finally, `platform` depends on `config`.

Start importing these extensions from top to down. Start with `config` and than go ahead with `platform`. After that, import the first extension that depends only on `platform` and so on. Choose `Eclipse` when asked for `Import project from external model` (from eclipse plugin in Intellij). After every import `build` the whole project in Intellij to prevent compile and jar dependencies errors.

I'm working with 29 Hybris extensions and 6 custom extensions in one project quite happily.

Comment: ksokol I don't see there is any problem using Intellij for Hybris. Many developers in my company uses IntelliJ. Lani1234 , can you share more on what issues you are facing? it may be more of an IntelliJ understanding issues than hybris.

Comment: How would you start importing? which one is the import project part? platform?extensions are the modules? what about config folder? when would it be imported?

Answer (score 3):

[Hybris Integration Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7525?pr=) provides impex highlighting and also have ability finding platform extensions successfully. If your custom hybris architecture related with hybris standards ( for example use custom folder inside bin directory etc.) then you can easily import your project according to extension xmls files, If not i suggest you to import your project as an eclipse project then "build" -> "make project" then try to added neccessary modules which gives a compilation error. Intellij & hybris integration works very well.

Answer (score 0):

Install plugin: **SAP Commerce Developers Toolset**

1. Open **File** > **Setting** > **Plugin**
2. Search the plugin by name > Install

Steps to import:

1. Click on **File** > **New** > **Project from existing sources..**.
2. Navigate to **bin** folder of your hybris project. > click **ok**
3. Choose **Import Project from External Model** > choose **hybris**
4. Click on **next** to keep every setting as default.
5. Change your JDK version (if any)
6. Click on **finish** to import Hybris Project.

Referencing to this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TT0Bv1USjWk